# Android: Custom Gridview data are not binding at first time

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-gridview

I make a gridview to display icons list(image & text) by reading data from Firebase DB, at the first time calling that activity the gridview display blank. Only after I change the orientation then data are loaded.

Please advise how can I make it display at first time.(this is my first time developing Android app and never code Java before)
Thanks

Below is my code:

```
            package com.abc.expensestracker;
```

> ```
>           import android.app.Activity;
>           import android.content.Intent;
>           import android.os.Bundle;
>           import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
>           import android.view.View;
>           import android.widget.AdapterView;
>           import android.widget.GridView;
>
>           import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
>           import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
>           import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
>           import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
>           import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
>
>           import java.util.ArrayList;
>
>           public class NewCategoryIconListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>
>               private GridView mIconListGridView;
>               private IconsListGridViewAdapter mIconListGridViewAdapter;
>               public ArrayList<IconsImageGridItemData> mIconsImageArrData = null;
>
>               private DatabaseReference mIconImagesRef;
>
>
>               @Override
>               protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>                   setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_category_icon_list);
>
>
>                   mIconListGridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.icons_list_gridview);
>                   mIconImagesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Iconimages");
>
>
>                   mIconsImageArrData = new ArrayList<IconsImageGridItemData>();
>                   setListData();
>
>                   mIconListGridViewAdapter = new IconsListGridViewAdapter(this,R.layout.icons_single_item_layout,mIconsImageArrData);//(this, R.layout.icons_single_item_layout, mGridData);
>                   mIconListGridView.setAdapter(mIconListGridViewAdapter);
>
>
>                   mIconListGridViewAdapter.setGridData(mIconsImageArrData);
>
>
>
>                   mIconListGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
>                       @Override
>                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
>
>                           //Get item at position
>                           IconsImageGridItemData item = (IconsImageGridItemData) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
>                           String selectedIconURL = item.getIconURL();
>
>                           //send back the selected icon to parent activity
>                           Intent returnIntent = getIntent();
>                           returnIntent.putExtra("icon_URL",selectedIconURL);
>                           setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
>                           finish();
>                       }
>                   });
>               }
>
>
>               /****** Function to set data in ArrayList *************/
>               public void setListData()
>               {
>
>                     mIconImagesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
>                       @Override
>                       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
>
>                           for(DataSnapshot categorySnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
>                               String iconURL = categorySnapshot.child("iconURL").getValue(String.class);
>
>                               final IconsImageGridItemData iconsImageData = new IconsImageGridItemData();
>                               /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
>                               iconsImageData.setIconURL(iconURL);
>
>
>
>                               /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
>                               mIconsImageArrData.add(iconsImageData);
>                           }
>                       }
>
>                       @Override
>                       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
>
>                       }
>                   });
>               }
>
>           }
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form your above code what I can understand is, task inside `setListData();` are completing after the execution of

`mIconListGridViewAdapter.setGridData(mIconsImageArrData);`

One simple change should work.  in side your setListData() function after finishing of for inside eventlistener's onDataChange() function

```
 /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList **********/
                                  mIconsImageArrData.add(iconsImageData);
                              }// For finish 
                          mIconListGridViewAdapter.setGridData(mIconsImageArrData);
                     }// end of onDataChange
```

this will make sure your adapter is getting data just after finishing data copying in mIconsImageArrData

Note:- I am assuming that you are certainly calling notifyDataSetChanged(); in setGridData  function copying data .

Comment: Thank you, this solve my issue. Hope I can apply this same method where binding Custom RecyclerView which I encountered the same issue.

Comment: Yes it will work as adapter is used to update the data in list/Recycler view, Only thing that need to care is `notifyDataSetChanged()` called after having data available in your Array/ArrayList or whatever type of data collection you use. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You need to notify the adapter that you have added an item.
So in your adapter do this:

```
public void add (IconsImageGridItemData iconsImageData) {
     mIconsImageArrData.add (0, iconsImageData);
     notifyItemInserted(0); //position to add the item
 }
```

Then in your setListData:

```
final IconsImageGridItemData iconsImageData = new IconsImageGridItemData();
                          /******* Firstly take data in model object ******/
                          iconsImageData.setIconURL(iconURL);
                          adapter.add (iconsImageData);



                          /******** Take Model Object in ArrayList**********/
                         // mIconsImageArrData.add(iconsImageData);
```

Comment: thank you for the prompt answer. but  `notifyItemInserted(0);` is unknow method in my Adapter class.